# NSMutable Array returning NULL when NSLog

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null, nsmutablearray

So I have an NSMutable array that I populate in viewDidLoad and then I NSLog it and it returns NULL in the console... I have looked around on stack-overflow and the apple reference and cannot find a solution to my problem.

Heres the code I used:

```
//Populate array
-(void)populateArray{
[TextArray addObject:@"Text1"]; 
[TextArray addObject:@"Text2"]; 
[TextArray addObject:@"Text3"]; 
[TextArray addObject:@"Text4"]; 
[TextArray addObject:@"Text5"]; 
NSLog(@"%@",TextArray);
NSLog(@"%@",[TextArray objectAtIndex:1]);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
TextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self populateArray];
}
```

And in the .h file

```
NSMutableArray *TextArray;
```

Thanks in advanced!
~Matt

Comment: Same code works fine for me. Can you change NSLog to say NSLog(@"TextArray :%@",TextArray); and NSLog(@"ObjectAtIndex %@",[TextArray objectAtIndex:1]); to make sure NULL is printed to console from this piece of code.

Comment: Try to rename variable `TextArray` to `textArray`. It is magic and I dont know if it would help, so I've just put this answer in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code you posted does not contain enough information for us to provide a specific answer. chances are, the methods are not being called in the order you expect them (e.g. populateArray is called from another point before viewDidLoad).

some assertions should help diagnose this:

```
//Populate array
-(void)populateArray
{
    assert(nil != self.textArray && "you need to create an array");

    [self.textArray addObject:@"Text1"];
    [self.textArray addObject:@"Text2"];
    [self.textArray addObject:@"Text3"];
    [self.textArray addObject:@"Text4"];
    [self.textArray addObject:@"Text5"];

    assert(5 == [self.textArray count] && "populateArray has been called twice or serious threading error");

    NSLog(@"%@",textArray);
    NSLog(@"%@",[textArray objectAtIndex:1]);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    assert(nil == self.textArray && "you need to clear your array (e.g. in viewDidUnload) or check if it has already been populated");

    self.textArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self populateArray];

    assert(5 == [self.textArray count] && "populateArray has been called twice or serious threading error");
}
```

lastly, if this array never changes, it's going to be much simpler to create this in your initializer rather than lazily. such an array will not require much memory, in case that was your concern.

**Update** the construct takes this form:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (nil != self){
        textArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Text1", @"Text2", @"Text3", @"Text4", @"Text5", nil];
// ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

lastly, `viewDidLoad` may be certainly be called multiple times on the same instance. the system unloads (then lazily reloads) views in low memory conditions.

Comment: There’s [NSAssert](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert), too.

Comment: @Bavarious +1 i just default to using more primitive assertion mechanisms because i refactor often (e.g. self is no longer in the current scope and i have to rewrite it), and i have a lot of code which is not compiled as objc. i like to keep assert calls to one family where possible. nevertheless, NSAssert is useful for a lot of people.

Comment: How would i create this in the initializer? And @Justin also the populateArray method is only being called once...